# How can this be written better?

Tags: c#, math, casting

```
private int OffsetToBlockNumber(int offset) {
            return (int)(Math.Floor((double)(offset / 0x1000)) - (double)0xc);
}
```

I'm making a class to read a type of file that is divided into blocks sized 4096 bytes, or 0x1000 in hex. The first block is at 0xC000, so that's why I'm subtracting 0xC from the result..

Anyway, the problem is that when I tried:

```
Math.Floor(offset / 0x1000) - 0xC
```

It said the call is ambiguous between the decimal and double types, so I cast them into doubles, and then the result into an int. It seems pretty dumb to do it this way, so I was hoping someone could shed some light on a better way.

Comment: Use integer division, `offset / 0x1000` already truncates without having to mess with Floor() and doubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shifting right 12 is the same as dividing by `0x1000`.  Your original expression can be expressed as:

```
return (offset >> 12) - 0xc;
```

Although I wonder if you actually meant to subtract `0xc` before dividing/shifting?

Comment: Gratulations for remembering how processors and fast integer math work ;) +1. Nice to see someone in the modern world actually still knowing how to program.